# find $K$ such that $K/Z(K)=G$

Tags: group-theory

Let $p$ is a prime number and $n\in \mathbb N$, $H$ a group such that $h\in H$ implies that $o(h)=p^rm$ where $(p,m)=1$ and $r<n$. I want to show that there does not exist a group $K$ such that $K/Z(K)=G$ where $G=\mathbb Z_{p^n}\times H$.

I've tried to find generating set $S$ of $G$ such that for $x\in G\setminus \{1\}$ we have $x\in \langle s\rangle$ for every $s\in S$.

Comment: Does $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ here mean $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$, the group of integers mod $p^n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose such a $K$ exists, and let $g \in K$ be an inverse image of a generator of the direct factor $C_{p^n}$ of $G$. I will prove that $g^{p^{n-1}} \in Z(K)$, which is a contradiction.

Let $k \in K$. Then $k = g^i h$ for some $i$ and some element $h$ that maps onto $H$. So the order of $h$ modulo $Z(K)$ is $p^rm$ with $r \le n-1$ and $(p,m)=1$.

Now, since all of the commutators involved lie in $Z(K)$, we have $[g^{mp^{n-1}},k] = [g^{mp^{n-1}},h] = [g,h]^{mp^{n-1}} = [g,h^{mp^{n-1}}] = 1$.

So $\langle g^{mp^{n-1}},Z(K) \rangle = \langle g^{p^{n-1}},Z(K) \rangle \in C_K(k)$ and hence $g^{p^{n-1}} \in Z(K)$ as claimed.

Comment: I have trouble with "all of the commutators involved lie in Z(K)"

Comment: @user108209 it is not hard to see that $[h,g]\in Z(K)$ and for next line, use the identity $[x,yz]=[x,z][x,y]^z$.